# How to sudo chmod -R 777 * including hidden files?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, chmod, hidden-files

Basically what I want to do is all in the title. If I want to grant read, write and execute permissions for everybody in a folder then I usually do:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

How can I extend this command to include hidden files and folders (starting with a dot) e.g. like `.env`? Because in the command above those are not affected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Universal:

```
chmod 777 -R ./* ./.[!.]*
```

Bash has this command

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

to also include hidden files in commands (`shopt -u dotglob` to disable that behaviour) if you want to stick to using `sudo chmod -R 777 *`.

- It will break your system if you execute it from the wrong directory.
- NEVER use a bare `*` but use `./*`.
- the shopt method is more secure than the universal one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more control, you can use .* for all your hidden files on the path you want to chmod.

Comment: Only files starting by .* will be affected.  The OP wants ALL files.